# how make link without reload all page with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want create some pages like facebook to load data without changing page/header or chat-bar in footer. I know I can use this code:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.load").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

But I have one problem. I want to give jQuery add-on data like.

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/profile123" //for example send-more-data="its-profile-link" //and send even more data like: even-more-data="ID:12235663">go to this profile</a>
```

so I can do more things with this like:

```
if (send-more-data=="its-profile-link") {
  $id = even-more-data="ID:12235663" //posted on link with jquery
  mysql_Query("select * from users where id =  $id")
}
elseif {
//////
}
```

so its possible i send more data with ID in  or class or somethings else?  Please give me an example. And tell me is it better using `.load()` or  `$.ajax()`?

Comment: I think you are looking for this solution , just you need based on click event... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878365/loading-more-items-from-database-infinite-scroll

Comment: Omar can you please give me example with $.ajax?

Comment: something like this `$.ajax({
Type: "GET",
url: 'http://mysite.com/profile123',
data: { ID }, 
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
success: function(data) { do something with retrieved data } });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can pass get params into link:

```
    $(function(){
        $("a.load").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content").load($(this).attr("href")+"?data1="+$(this).attr("some-data")+"&data2="+$(this).attr("some-more-data"));
        });
    });
```

**OR**

You can use even better - the mighty AJAX:

```
    $(function(){
            $("a.load").click(function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                var link = $(this).attr("href");
                var param1 = $(this).attr("some-data");
                var param2 = $(this).attr("some-more-data");
                /* //$.post example
                $.post(link, { data1: param1, data2: param2 },function(data) {
                   $("#content").html(data);
                }); */
                //or $.ajax - basically the same thing
                $.ajax({
                  url: link,
                  data: { data1: param1, data2: param2 },
                  success: function(result) {
                    $("#content").html(result);
                  }
                });
            });
        });
```

Then in php:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['data1']=="its-profile-link"){
$id = @$_REQUEST['data2'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id); //or $id = (int)$id; if id is always integer.
   mysql_Query("select * from users where id =  $id")
}
elseif{
//////
}
```

Comment: can you please give me example with $.ajax?

Comment: @masiharastooyi updated answer. Basically, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="my_a" some-data="asd">

console.log($('#my_a').attr('some-data')); // asd
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: True, sorry, accepted answer is better, I also upvoted it. However, keep up the good moderating work!